# How to exclude .map files from ASP.NET bundling

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification

I have a project that is using ASP.NET Bundling.  I am having an issue where the .map files are throwing an error on the client side even though I have explicitly excluded them from the bundling using the ignore list.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/stuff").IncludeDirectory(
            "~/Scripts/stuff/", "*.js", true));
bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*.map");
```

When I run the project I get a 500 error with the following message:

> The view 'The controller for path '/stuff/Charting.js.map' was not
>   found or does not implement IController.' or its master was not found
>   or no view engine supports the searched locations.

How do I get this to properly ignore the .map files in the directory while bundling?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you shouldn't be having any real issues.

`.map` files allow a browser to download a full version of the minified JS. It is really for debugging purposes.

The `.map` missing shouldn't a problem. You only know it is missing, as the browser has had its Developer tools opened and is just informing you that the JS debugging won't be as good as it could be.

This is why libraries like jQuery have the full, the minified and the map file too.

See this article [for a full explanation of .map files](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/).

Alternatively, you could actually include the `.map` files in your project.

Comment: While this issue does not break the site it is an error I would like to take care of.  As I mentioned this is getting a 500 error with the text shown above.

Comment: hi @bechbd , any luck on solving this issue?

Comment: No I didn't find a resolution